# Is Modificator a word?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

Is the word "Modificator" valid - I've never see it before and it's not one I'm familiar with.

Comment: Did you check it in a dictionary?

Comment: Some dictionaries have it and some don't I think.

Comment: This contradicts what you're saying in your question, that *you've never seen it before*. However can you provide the definition from some of those that have it?

Comment: @Neeku It could mean that your pertinent first comment has been a galvaniser-into-action.

Comment: What do you mean "some dictionaries have it and some don't *I think*"? I doubt Neeku was meaning to ask for your *opinion* on whether dictionaries have the word. His point was that you should actually check.

Comment: Anyway. Clearly *modificator* is a word. Whether it is a word that has any meaning is a different question, and whether that meaning matches the one you are after is a different question still. But since you have not specified what meaning you are after, it is impossible for us to say if *modificator* appropriately expresses it.

Comment: It's French, and a very common kind of mistake for French people to make in English even when the rest of their English seems immaculate. (There are a number of words which, in English, end in *ier*, but the French cognates end in *icateur*.)

Comment: You're simply looking for "modifier".  It's not a popular or "correct" usage.  Wherever you saw it, the person was, simply, wrong.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Yeah, obviously! By the way, *she* here, no *he* around. xD

Comment: @Neeku: oh sorry, it was, um, er, a *singular he*.

Comment: @RegDwight 'Clearly _modificator_ is a word. Whether it is a word that has any meaning is a different question' is extremely worrying. Although conflicting definitions of 'word' exist, I don't think I've ever seen one in a linguistic work that allows totally meaningless white-space-bounded strings. 'Nonsense word' is a misnomer and a compound noun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that it is not a valid word.

[Collins English Dictionary says:](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/spellcheck/english/Modificator?showCookiePolicy=true)

> Sorry, no results for “Modificator” in the Collins English Dictionary.

[Oxford English Dictionary says:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/all/?q=Modificator)

> No results found for “Modificator”.

[The suffix "-ator" is](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ator#Suffix)

> -ator
>
> used to form [agent nouns](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/agent_noun), usually from verbs that have the ending -ate

And "Modifate" is not a word.

The correct word for what you are looking for is a "Modifier"

Answer (score -4):

In English "Modificator" is not meaning anything
Actually It has not relevance to the English

Modifica That's an italian word
Modifica = Edit

You're sure you in english site :D

Comment: Please make sure your sentences are correct and grammatical before posting.