# Can the word "dialogue" be used when two characters have short interaction, but only one is talking?

Tags: word-usage, terminology

When I was writing [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61700/explanation-of-tatas-words) on *Movies & TV SE* I was really tempted to use the word *dialogue* to describe the interaction between two characters. However the problem is that in the described scene one character says only one short sentence and the other doesn't say anything.

*Dialogue* (in a book, play or film) [is defined](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dialogue) as:

> a conversation between two or more people as a feature of a book, play,
>   or film

This means that this kind of interaction shouldn't be called a *dialogue*. However it's not a [monologue](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/monologue) either.

Can the word *dialogue* be used to describe a short interaction between characters with only one of them talking?

Comment: You might want to add a modificator to clarify the nuance of meaning you wish to convey. E.g. a "unilateral dialogue" or "one-sided dialogue" or "one-way dialogue".

Comment: @Felix Goldberg [You might want to modify 'modificator'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193340/is-modificator-a-word).

Comment: The bartender was listening to his only customer's, of the night, long and arduous monologue.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth [Perhaps not](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/modificator)

Comment: @Graffito Not really, because it's only one short sentence, not _a long, tedious speech_.

Comment: I'm rather surprised that ODO includes it. According to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=modifier%2Cmodificator&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmodifier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmodificator%3B%2Cc0), it's an extremely rare variant. The related post here didn't recommend its use. And I've not come across it in any decent grammar. Or anywhere else until now. I'd class it as _unidiomatic_, and ELU looks at the way English is normally used.

Comment: the simple answer "Can the word dialogue be used to describe a short interaction between characters with only one of them talking?" is YES, in actual everyday filmmaking, you'd say "dialogue" (essentially meaning, come to think of it "there are two actors in the scene, coverage of both") even if one doesn't do much talking.

Comment: Graffito and Blessed: your example of "monologue" relates to when you (rarely, or humorously) use "monologue" regarding humans interacting.  (So, my wife will tell me "stop monologuing!" if I'm being long-winded.) The question here is only regarding terms of art within filmmaking (or playwriting).

Comment: @JoeBlow This was actually my way of thinking. Why not writing an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While one is talking the other may be responding non-verbally. So, in my opinion there is some sort of conversation/ dialogue, or duologue as you please.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above I'd say that YES, in actual everyday filmmaking, you'd use the term "dialogue" (essentially meaning: "there are two actors in the scene, coverage of both") even if one doesn't do much talking.  In the OP's question of how are these terms used in film/plays, a "monologue" is more a formalism where "a 'speech' is inserted in the work".  (Consider say the "villain's monologue".) That's different from a dialogue where, as it happens, one isn't talking much.